# Mapping a list into a reference list

Tags: python, list, mapping

I am trying to make this as clear as I can. Please let me know if I should clarify anything.

I have a long list of variables in a list in the following format -

```
L = ["Fruit", "Transportation", "Housing", "Food", "Education"]
```

I would like to map a shorter list into it. The shorter list does not have each but only some of the variables in the long list. For instance -

```
S = ["Fruit", "Food"]
```

What I am interested in obtaining is the binary values of the short list while it maps into the L list.

With S as an example, it should be:

```
S = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

I tried map(S, L) but clearly a list is not callable.

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

What would be a good way to do this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

By using a list comprehension that takes every value in `L` and if it is contained inside `S` it returns a value of `1`, and, if not, it returns a value of `0`:

```
m = [1 if subval in S else 0 for subval in L]
```

the result is:

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[int(x in S) for x in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's list comprehension as follow:

```
ans=[1 if x in S else 0 for x in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried map(S, L) but clearly a list is not callable.

But its methods are:

```
>>> map(S.count, L)
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

(This one assumes there are no duplicates in S. If that's not the case, you could for example use `map(list(set(S)).count, L)` instead.)